# How to handle the form's KeyPress event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a program in which I am using this code,

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{          
    if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57)
    {
        txtbox.Text = txtbox.Text + e.KeyChar.ToString();
    }
}
```

But I am not getting key pressed on my text box.I am unable to find the failure reason.

Comment: Keyboard events are fired on the control that has the focus.  That will never be the form when it has a control that can receive the focus, like that textbox you have on your form.  Pretty unclear why you are not using the KeyPress event of the "txtbox" control.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538(v=vs.110).aspx) you have to set [`Form.KeyPreview`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to `true`, default is false. Otherwise you can't handle the form's `KeyPress` event.

> When this property is set to `true`, the form will receive all `KeyPress`,
>   `KeyDown`, and `KeyUp` events.

Comment: Thanks alot for your generous help.

Comment: @MariaSheikh: I'm glad to hear that you have got it wworking. Consider to accept the answer then.